# What is the number of triangles that can be drawn between n noncollinear points without repeating a side?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

I'm part of a tournament where teams can compete in either two or three way competitions. The goal is to have everyone face everyone, and maximize the number of 3 way competitions, without anyone facing anyone twice. Ideally we would then optimize for an equal or near equal number of 3 way and 2 way competitions for each team.

It occurred to me that this is the same as what I stated in the title. Given n points, how many triangles can be drawn between n points without repeating any lines? I know that you're looking at $ 
 \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}
$ potential lines between the points, and each triangle would take up 3 of those lines. Because of that, you would have, at most, $ 
 \dfrac{n(n-1)}{6}
$ triangles without repeat.

However, is there a way to find out how many triangles can be drawn without brute force trial and error? If so, is there a way to show what works? If not has someone already looked at this?

So far, here's what a friend and I have found:

```
|    n |  ideal | found |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|    3 |      1 |     1 |
|    4 |      2 |     1 |
|    5 |   3.33 |     2 |
|    6 |      5 |     4 |
|    7 |      7 |     5 |
|    8 |   9.33 |     8 |
|    9 |     12 |    12 |
|   10 |     15 |    12 |
```

Thank you.